# Java8 - update more than one list based on a POJO

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I have a use case as below.

1. POJO
2. If POJO is not null and not empty, add the pojo to a set.
3. Add one element from pojo to another set
4. Add another element from pojo to a list

I have something as below.

```
Optional.ofNullable(pojo)
        .ifPresent(uniquePojoSet::add) //Added pojo to a set
        .//Add city from pojo to a set
        .//Add userName from pojo to a list
```

Here, `ifPresent` returns `void`. I am not sure how to handle this? I need to add only if the elements are not null and not empty.

Please advise to be written in a standard way also.

Current implementation:

```
if(pojo != null && !pojo.isEmpty()) {
  //Add Pojo to set
  if(pojo.getProperty1() != null) {
   //Add to another set
  }
  if(pojo.getProperty2() != null) {
   //Add to another list
  }
}
```

I referred [this](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/java8-optional.html) But couldn't match my requirement exactly

Comment: Use a method called `void populateCollections(POJO pojo)` that does it for you and call it under `ifPresent`.

Comment: I have those three objects in the current context. I need to pass those three references also to the method. Then java-7 way is better looking.

Comment: for one, no one knows without you sharing what the current implementation looks like, and for another if it's looking better than using `Optional`, what is the reason to look out for an alternate?

Comment: @Naman Added more at the end.

Comment: the details are still incomplete, what is the type of `pojo`? how does `!pojo.isEmpty()` gets checked with the `Optional.ofNullable` in the code shared? where are you adding other attributes? do they all have a similar type(and similar checks)?

Comment: You can use `ofNullable(..).orElseThrow(...)` to obtain the instance, throwing a detailed exception if the value is not present. If you want "nothing" to occur when not present, you'll need to return after an `isPresent()` check. You could use `Optional#map`. I would suggest allowing the Pojo to populate the list with it's details (maybe through some interface). You could then do something like `POJO p = ofNullable(..).orElse(new BlankPojo())`, calling `p.populate(entities)`, where `entities` is an object allowing the Pojo to add it's details. (BlankPojo doesn't add)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Optional` is a value-class and immutable you can store immediate steps and do:

```
Optional<Pojo> notEmpty = Optional.ofNullable(pojo).filter(pojo -> !pojo.isEmpty());
notEmpty.ifPresent(uniquePojoSet::add);
notEmpty.map(Pojo::getCity).ifPresent(citySet::add);
notEmpty.map(Pojo::getUserName).ifPresent(userNameSet::add);
```

I think the more readable way would be a simple `if` cascade.

Comment: Thanks. It works as if pojo type has an isEmpty method.

Answer (score 1):

The article you referred suggests converting POJO fields to `Optional`s. Another option is to make getters return `Optional`s, for example:

```
public class Pojo {

    private String city;
    private String username;

    public Optional<String> getCity() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(city);
    }

    public Optional<String> getUsername() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(username);
    }
}
```

And then you could use them as follows:

```
Optional.ofNullable(pojo).ifPresent(p -> {
    uniquePojoSet.add(p);
    p.getCity().ifPresent(cities::add);
    p.getUsername().ifPresent(usernames::add);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for understanding my question.